# Using html2Canvas to capture SVG image

Tags: javascript, html, svg, html2canvas, canvg

I'm using [html2Canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) library and trying to make a screenshot of a SVG with this code:

```
var svgElements= $container.find('svg');
svgElements.each(function (){
    var canvas, xml;

    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.className = "screenShotTempCanvas";
    //convert SVG into a XML string
    xml = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(this);
    xml = xml.replace(/xmlns=\"http:\/\/www\.w3\.org\/2000\/svg\"/, '');
    canvg(canvas, xml);
    $(canvas).insertAfter(this); 

    this.className"tempHide";
    $(this).hide();
}); 
$container.find('.screenShotTempCanvas').remove(); 
$container.find('.tempHide').show().removeClass('tempHide');
```

but my problem is that I have a input (foreignObject) inside the svg. The screenshot that it takes, contains only the svg elements. Anyone has a solution for this? How I can I capture all the elements on page?

Thank!

Comment: This is a known issue in canvg. It does not support foreignObject at its current state.

Comment: Can you post an example of the type of SVG you want to render? Can't you do something like `canvasCtx2d.draw( new Img.src = "data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8," + svg.parentNode.innerHTML, 0, 0 )` (pseudo code, the image thing needs to be multiline for this, but you get the gist).